# idea: Unknown compiler option 'typeRoots'

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, configuration

I novice in javascript and related technologies.
I try to write code in my favourite IDE idea.

I write code on typesript. Sometimes I see error:

```
Error:Cannot start compiler process:  Error: Parse tsconfig error [{"messageText":"Unknown compiler option 'typeRoots'.","category":1,"code":5023}]
```

[image]

I have found only one menu in configuration but I don't inderstand what should I do.

[image]

idea version 15.0.1

Answer (score 0):

According to screenshot your IDE uses 1.6.2 version of ts compiler (bundled one). *typeRoots* were added in typescript 2, that's why you're getting this error.

You can install latest version of typescript using npm and instruct the IDE to use it:

> Compiler Version | Edit

Comment: This issue disappeared but I see "Error:Cannot start compiler process:  ReferenceError: setTimeout is not defined" although I don't use setTimeout in code

Answer (score 0):

1: Run

```
npm i typescript@2.0.0 -g
```

and

```
npm install
```

2: Go to settings and change the typescript version to your local node_modules/typescript/lib and apply.

Then the error should disappear.